# Right margin cut-off when printing A3 report in Oracle Report Builder 6i

Tags: oracle, printing, report

i am using Oracle Report Builder 6i for A3(W:420mm x H:297mm) Landscape Report.
when i print that report in RICOH Pro C9100 printer, right margin cut off. Margin:0, Page setup: A3 landscape. everything correct. Other Printers Printing the same report Perfectly. let me know the solutions.

Comment: Buy a new printer?

Comment: no, i need to configure the report for that printer